# How to get generic type by Type hash code & invoke an event with it?

Tags: c#, networking, serialization, deserialization

I am working on the C# networking solution and right now I am working on the (custom) packets system.
My project contains 2 serialization classes - `Serializer` and `Deserializer`. The first one is converting primitive types into byte[] buffer, and second one is reversing the process.

Those 2 classes contain 2 generic type serializers:

```cs
// Serializer
public void Write<T>(T packet) where T : IPacket, new()
{
    packet.Serialize(this);
}

// Deserializer
public T Read<T>() where T : IPacket, new()
{
    T t = new T();
    t.Deserialize(this);
    return t;
}
```

The `IPacket` interface has only 2 method definitions:

- `Serialize(Serializer serializer);`
- `Deserialize(Deserializer deserializer);`

And now, we are going into the source of my problem.

My ClientInstance class (high-level networking), looks like that (only parts that matter for the problem):

```cs
public void InitializeClient()
{
    lowLevelNetworking.DataReceivedEvent += OnDataReceived;
}

public void SendPacket(T packet) where T : IPacket, new()
{
    ushort packetId = Utils.UShortHashCode(typeof(T).FullName);
    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
    serializer.WriteUShort(packetId);
    serializer.Write(packet);
    lowLevelNetworking.Send(serializer.ToByteArray());
    serializer.Dispose();
}

void OnDataReceived(byte[] data)
{
   Deserializer deserializer = new Deserializer(data);
   ushort packetId = deserializer.ReadUShort();

   // ... and here we have a problem.
}

public void AddPacketListener<T>(Action<T> listener)
{
   // with this thing too...
}
```

This is how I see the OnDataReceived:

- Create a deserializer
- Get the packet ID
- Get proper `T` value out of the packet ID
- Deserialize `T`, like `SuperPacket packet = deserializer.Read<SuperPacket>();`
- Invoke OnPacketReceived event with `T` (in this case `SuperPacket`) & execute methods that subscribed to SuperPacket only.

*Example packet:*

```cs
public struct SuperPacket : IPacket
{
    public int value1;
    public string value2;

    public void Serialize(Serializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.WriteInt(value1);
        serializer.WriteString(value2);
    }

    public void Deserialize(Deserializer deserializer)
    {
        value1 = deserializer.ReadInt();
        value2 = deserializer.ReadString();
    }
}
```

Let's now take a look how I see example packet listener:

```cs
public class Listener
{
    public ClientInstance clientInstanceRef;

    public void Start()
    {
        clientInstanceRef.AddPacketListener<SuperPacket>(OnSuperPacketReceived);
    }

    void OnSuperPacketReceived(SuperPacket packet)
    {
        //... and here some stuff with that packet.
    }
}
```

So, to summarize my problem - I am looking for a way to:

- Get proper type basing on it's ID
- Read it using `T Read();` method
- Invoke all methods that subscribed to the `T` packet (using `AddPacketListener(..)` method)
- Register expected handlers in `AddPacketListener(...);`

**Note 1**

I cannot guarantee order of packets, etc, I use UDP socket.

**Note 2**

Each packet ID (hash code of type) is unique per packet, my code warrants it.

Comment: There is no guarantee that 2 different types won't have the same hash code.

Comment: @Magnetron There is actually, gonna modify the question

Comment: Even if you can guarantee that they are unique, hash functions usually are one-way only. Either you implement your own hash function that is reversible or you have to keep the same mapping in both client and server. With that, you can recover the type and deserialize based on that type.